# Having problems calling function within bash script

Tags: bash

I've been working on our intro scripting assignment, and am having issues calling functions within the script. I am in the second portion of the assignment, and I am just testing to make sure what I have is (hopefully) going to work.  I have gathered some directories, and ask a yes or no question.  When I get a 'y', I wrote a little function that I call, and when I get a 'n' I have another function, both simple echoes.  What is the issue?

```
part_two(){
    answer=""
    for value in "$@";do
      echo "$value"
      while [ "$answer" != "y" -a "$answer" != "n" ]
      do 
        echo -n "Would you like to save the results to a file? (y/n): "
        read answer
      done
      if [ "$answer" = "n" ]
        then 
          part_six
      elif [ "$answer" = "y" ]
        then 
          part_five
      fi 
    done
}

part_two $@

part_five(){
    echo -n "working yes";
}

part_six(){
    echo -n "working no";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as always.

Comment: We can't tell you the issue until you tell us the unwanted behavior you are experiencing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Much like in C a function must be defined before it's used. In your code snippet you are calling part_two (which is calling part_five and part_six) before declaring the two functions.

Have you tried moving their definitions to the start of the script?

EDIT:

In most cases, the best way to deal with this in Bash is to simply define all functions at the start of the script before executing any actual commands. The order of the definitions does not really matter - the shell only looks up a function when it's about to use it - so generally there are no dependency issues etc. that you may have to think about.

EDIT 2:

There *are* cases where you may not be able to just define a function at the start of the script. A common case is when you use conditional constructs to dynamically select or modify the declaration of a function e..g.:

```
if [[ "$1" = 0 ]]; then
    function show() {
        echo Zero
    }
else
    function show() {
        echo Not-zero
    }
fi
```

In these cases *you* have to make sure that each function call happens after that function (and any others that it calls) is declared.

EDIT 3:

In bash a function declaration is actually the `function foo() { ... }` block where you define its implementation - and yes, the `function` keyword is not strictly necessary. There are no function prototypes as in C - they would not make sense anyway because shell scripts are generally parsed as they are executed. Newer Bash version do read a script at once, but they mostly check for syntax errors and not for logical errors such as this one.

BTW the official term is "function *declaration*", but even the Bash info page uses "declaration" and "definition" interchangeably.

Comment: Thank you.  We touched on functions in class, but only for moments, was not aware of their need to be defined.

Comment: @mrwienerdog: In other words, move this line to the bottom: `part_two $@`.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

Running your provided script file (here named `question.sh`) with at least one parameter, e.g. `./question abc`, then answering the question, results in either message on *stderr*:

- when answering`y`: `question.sh: line 15: part_five: command not found`
- when providing `n`: `question.sh: line 12: part_six: command not found`

This is because (roughly speaking) [*Bash* executes "commands" as soon as they are encountered](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html). So in your script, as soon as *Bash* reaches those lines 15 or 12, Bash has not processed the [*declarations* for shell functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html) `part_five` or `part_six`; their declarations begin at lines 22 and 26, respectively.

[Bash will go through a couple of "search strategies" for finding a "command" *by name*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Search-and-Execution.html), ultimatively trying to find an *executable* by that name available on `$PATH`.
As there are (most likely) no executables by the name `part_five` or `part_six`, Bash didn't find something to execute, resulting in the "`command not found`" *stderr* message (and [returning to your script with exit status `127`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html)).

As a comparison, on the interactive Bash prompt, trying to execute `part_five` or `part_six` will (most likely) give the same failure message and exit status `127`:

```
$ part_five 
bash: part_five: command not found

$ echo $?
127
```

### Solution

One solution is to move the shell function declarations for `part_five` or `part_six` *before* the `part_two $@` command; this allows *Bash* to see and "learn" the *declarations* for shell functions `part_five` or `part_six` before their execution:

```
part_two(){
    answer=""
    for value in "$@";do
      echo "$value"
      while [ "$answer" != "y" -a "$answer" != "n" ]
      do 
        echo -n "Would you like to save the results to a file? (y/n): "
        read answer
      done
      if [ "$answer" = "n" ]
        then 
          part_six
      elif [ "$answer" = "y" ]
        then 
          part_five
      fi 
    done
}

part_five(){
    echo -n "working yes";
}

part_six(){
    echo -n "working no";
}

part_two $@
```

Coincidentally, this follows a *best practice* from [*Google's Bash Shell Style Guide*](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#main) – wrapping the "main" part of a script file in a dedicated `main` function, then declaring other functions, then ending the script with `main "$@"`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# main function idiom
# see https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#main
main() {
  echo "before"
  
  local exit_status
  after_main_function_declared_function
  # execution of above 'after_main_function_declared_function' will succeed
  exit_status="$?"
  
  echo "after, exit status=${exit_status}"
}

after_main_function_declared_function() {
  echo "this comes from function 'after_main_function_declared_function'"
}

main "$@"
```

Especially for longer script files, this *main function idiom* puts the main script task at the  beginning of the file, and places the "finer details" in reusable functions below it – just as it is done in other programming languages.